# Is an aircraft maintenance diploma under EASA recognized for studying in the US?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-maintenance, easa-regulations, engineer

I have a diploma certificate of aircraft maintenance engineering but I studied under EASA. So can I study and take the Bachelor degree in the USA without restarting all my study?

Comment: This question is unclear. Which Bachelor's degree are you intending to seek in the US?